# Aalert when dynamic html it's ready

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML that is loaded by jquery, I need a alert when it is fully loaded.

My Real HTML:

```
<div class="prerecord_main">
   <div id="merch">
   </div>
</div>
```

after prepend by jquery:

```
<div class="prerecord_main">
   <div id="merch">
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('document').on('ready', '#merch .product-container', function() {
   alert('works');
});
```

Comment: 1. You are missing a `'` in `$('document')` 2. What is your question?

Comment: when all 'product-container' are fully loaded to give me a alert.

Comment: What do you mean by "prepend by jquery"?  How does that happen?  Show some code.

Comment: `document` shouldn't be a string  ...`$(document)` also `on('ready'` is deprecated  ..see API docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument event. It will notify you if there is a new product-container added. For example:

```
$('.product-container').on('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', function() {
  console.log('new .product-container added');
};
```

You could also use the .livequery() jQuery plugin to do this too. For example:

```
$('.product-container').livequery(function() {
  console.log('new .product-container added');
});
```

As Ke Vin has pointed out - mutation events are deprecated. If you are worried about that, you can use a Mutation Observer like [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

Comment: Mutation events are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).